# Multiple same kind of column concatenation in another column of same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, concatenation

I have one table "Mytable" and in this i have multiple columns and now in this columns i have 100 columns with same name like "type1", "type2"..,"type99" and i am importing this value from csv. so now what i want to do is i want to combined all this column value in one single column in json format. 
Can any one suggest me how can i achieve?

Comment: How would you do it if you had a csv with 3 columns?

Comment: Publish your table's DDL (3 columns `type1, type2, type3` enough) and sample data (2-3 records) as `CREATE TABLE` + `INSERT INTO` scripts and desired CSV file content **for this data**.

Comment: @Strawberry i have multiple columns in CSV like name, contact details etc and plus this type1,type2, upto type 99.
so using LOAD INFILE function i am importing all data in MySQL but after that what i need to do is to combine all Type related coulmn in to one column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the json object as:

```
select json_object('type1', type1, 'type2', type2, . . . )
```

Alternatively, you might want an array.

You can then insert this into a new table.